# Does Protractor have "page.has_content" command?

Tags: javascript, rspec, protractor

I want to check if a web page has a `<h1>` element called "aaa".

With Rspec can I use `page.has_content?("aaa")` How about with Protractor?

Comment: page.has_content command does not need to specify the type of the DOM. That is the difference

Answer (score 2):

Assuming has_content is looking for an element with text, in Protractor, you could do something like...

In your page object:

```
// pass in the dom element and the text it should have
this.hasText = function(elm, text) {
    return element(by.cssContainingText(elm, text)).isDisplayed();
};
```

In your spec:

```
expect(page.hasText('h1', 'aaa')).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can locate the `h1` element with `aaa` text by XPath:

```
expect(element(by.xpath("//h1[. = 'aaa']")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```